# Hist of circular residual in R programme between -pi and pi

Tags: r, statistics

I have the data of error, firstly I need to transform the range of data between -pi and pi

then using code `hist(error)`

my question is how I can transform this data using code in R, if there exists code please tell me?

```
error<- c( 5.71444784 ,5.55435896 ,5.60671884, 5.19927462 ,4.81470000 ,5.53028500,
 0.87085808 ,5.37982604, 5.43760222 ,5.77523327, 5.68796681 ,5.54533123,
5.27149485 ,5.75717780 ,0.53623627 ,5.29496664 ,5.33288247 ,5.49297135,
 5.51343389 ,4.87307837 ,4.87849468 ,5.78305665, 0.13721761 ,5.91185037,
 5.50741540 ,5.72588264, 5.03918574, 4.14846564 ,5.25644862 ,0.57956841,
 0.37614739, 0.40864692, 5.92087811, 5.92689660, 5.72889189 ,5.64643955,
5.96902437, 5.91666449, 6.18508456 ,5.86249974 ,5.17279359, 5.37982604,
 5.25163450, 5.43098155, 5.73912232, 5.80592625 ,5.43940710, 4.84659734,
 5.76078923, 5.76379847, 5.76078923 ,5.78606589, 5.68977169 ,5.68375320,
 0.42790509 ,6.08939254, 4.89955940 ,5.53389643, 5.67954126 ,5.71324348,
 5.66930915 ,5.54111761 ,5.87273017, 5.86791605 ,5.50199909, 5.50199909,
 5.69699455 ,5.29737370 ,4.97117745, 5.62838408 ,5.77402891, 5.30640144,
 5.85106494 ,5.58926555 ,5.58926555 ,4.62271379 ,3.36547454, 6.19892642,
 0.28888093 ,6.09541103, 5.89499926 ,5.87453672, 5.67954126 ,5.46408326,
 1.44982681 ,0.24193736 ,0.77516606 ,5.88055521, 5.55435896, 5.58926555,
 5.58926555 ,5.39126084, 4.47466189, 0.06800662, 5.75777998, 5.44963921)
```

I try this problem by transforming the data handly .... and hist ... but the residual doesn't about zero.

Comment: What is the measurement unit of the data? degrees, radians, or something else. If they are directional data, you probably need to use circular statistics.

Comment: this data is circular in radian , all my need is transform the range of radian data between pi and --pi@dcarlson

Answer (score 1):

To compute the range from -pi to pi just subtract `pi` from the radian measurement since radians range from 0 to 2*pi:

```
error - pi
hist(error - pi)
```

But that does not give you what you want. You really need to use circular statistics to see what is going on:

```
install.packages("circular")
library(circular)
plot.circular(error, stack=TRUE)
```

[image: Circular Plot]

You can ignore the warning message. Notice that the data are not around zero. To plot a histogram we need to cut the data at pi and flip the values greater than pi:

```
errortrans <- ifelse(error<pi, error, error-2*pi)
# Alternate transform
# errortrans <- ifelse(error<pi, -error, 2*pi-error)
hist(errortrans, xlim=c(-pi, pi))
```

[image: Histogram]

Comment: can you hist the result , but this is not around the zero ??

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: can I accept this result about the residual(error) not around zero exactly???

Comment: how I can find Mean square error or error ???